# Java alternative to Windows Workflow Foundation

Tags: java, workflow, workflow-foundation

What Java alternatives are there to Windows Workflow Foundation? I am looking for something that provides at least the same features that WWF does, and has the same flexibility and relative ease of use. I would very much prefer a free solution.

Comment: A graphical designer would also be nice. Like Eclipse integration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several great workflow engines for Java [JBPM](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm/) is one.

Others can be found [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines).

Answer (score 2):

We've used OSWorkflow and had success with it. In particular, it was easy to integrate with Spring and Quartz.

http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/