# .net alternatives for available java programs

Tags: java, .net

I have seen some question asking java alternative for something which is available in .net

Example :
[Java alternative to Windows Workflow Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762499/java-alternative-to-windows-workflow-foundation)

I am interested to know if there is anything else that is available in java and we have  to look for an alternative in .net. I am a MS based technology developer and don't have much experience developing in java so I am interested to know about this.

Comment: This question is too open-ended.  There's a ton of stuff in Java that may or may not have a .NET equivalent.  Maybe pick out something you like in .NET (LINQ, WCF, etc.), and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I agree. Ask about something specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows Workflow Foundation is .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx)

There are many technologies in Java, that might not have equivalents in .NET

I think you should be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

[K2](http://www.k2.com/en/index.aspx) is a good alternative to WF.  Or maybe I misunderstand your question. :)